# How to change the title of xna screen in a class

Tags: c#, xna

I want to change the title of the screen in my Map class.
I know that in `Game1` you can use 
`this.Window.Title = "Level1";`

And I tought I give the GameWindow as a parameter in my `LoadContent` method in my Map class.

```
public class Map 
{
     public void LoadContent(ContentManager content, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, GameWindow gamewindow)
     {
       switch (currentLevel) 
       { 
            case 1:
                texture1 = content.Load<Texture2D>("skyLine");
                song = content.Load<Song>("music");
                gamewindow.Title = "Level 1";
                MediaPlayer.Play(song);
                break;
       }
    }
}
```

In my Game1 I tried to create a new instance of GameWindow but you can't do that since it is an abstract class.

So when I run my game it throws an `NullReferenceExceptionError` on `gameWindow.Title`. Thats because I can't make an instance of GameWindow. 
 
Is there a (different) solution to change the title of the screen in a class?

The code to call the LoadContent from Map:

```
map.LoadContent(this.Content, GraphicsDevice, this.Window);
```

Comment: did you find the new title set here being available in the caller of this class, may be something may be overriding ther

Comment: Are you passing `this.Window` to that `LoadContent()` method?

Comment: @itsme86 I also tried that, it stills throws an NullReferenceException

Comment: @Bas Can you post your code from `Game1` where you call your `map.LoadContent()` method?

Comment: @Bas Interesting. What if you change your parameter and just pass in `Game1` instead of the `Window` object? And then in the `LoadContent()` method do `game.Window.Title = "Level 1";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @itsme86 I got it working with the following code:

The method call in `Game1`: `map.LoadContent(this.Content, GraphicsDevice, this);`

`LoadContent` method in the map class:

```
public class Map 
{
     public void LoadContent(ContentManager content, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Game1 game)
     {
         switch (currentLevel) 
         { 
              case 1:
                   texture1 = content.Load<Texture2D>("skyLine");
                   song = content.Load<Song>("music");
                   game.Window.Title = "Level 1";
                   MediaPlayer.Play(song);
                break;
       }
    }
}
```